# How to use feature group?

Tags: feature-engineering

Let's say I have a data set like the following:

`file   group_a_co_1    group_a_co_2    group_b_co_1    group_b_co_2
file_1  0.8 0.2 0.3 0.7
file_2  0.1 0.9 0.2 0.8
file_3  0.5 0.5 0.7 0.3
...`

I wonder, whether there are ways/tricks to tell the model about the group information here: since group_a_co_1 + group_a_co_2 = 1 and the same goes for group_b. Somehow I figure if I expose the group information, the performance of my model will improve.

Answer (score 1):

The information in groups 'group_a_co_2' and 'group_b_co_2' are already redundant; they do not add more information to the model. Therefore they can be removed.
Adding even more redundant information will not improve your model further.

Comment: So you mean I just need group_a_co_1 and group_b_co_1 these two columns?

Comment: Yes, you will solve multicollinearity